# Super Secret Cookbook

Tags: logical-deduction, word, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

You requested the password for a super secret cookbook and received an SMS with the following content:

77733666688833 2555555 777772222337777 2663 777337555222233 84433 6688622337777777 9444844 3444444487777 8666 777766622233333 666 777 88 4 55 444 3 77 6 333 9999 99 4 333 444 888 33 8 44 777 33 33 7 666 5 7777 3 88 444 222 99 444 5 33 888 666 7777 55 4 55 888 44 333 7777 444 222 99 5 333 33 88 55 77 8 9 666 9999 33 2 88 4 77 8 9 666 555 666 666 77 333 444 888 33 222 2 8 9 666 555 88 33 22 88 99 4 444 3 666 66 333 444 888 33 8 9 666 222 2 333 666 88 777 8 7 666 77 999 8 4 444 3 333 66 9999 777 9 7777 444 99 9999 3 333 6 77 88 77

As a hint you were only told that the password is edible. Try to get the correct password!

---

Hint #1:

> At some point 32 symbols were used for encryption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take text (as writing on mobile phone keyboard):

> REMOVE ALL SPACES AND REPLACE THE NUMBERS WITH DIGITS TO PROCEDE/PROCEED ORUGKIDQMFZXGFIVETHREEPOJSDUICXIJEVOSKGKVHFSICXJFEUKQTWOZEAUGQTWOLOOQFIVECATWOLUEBUXGIDONFIVETWOCAFOURTPOQYTGIDFNZRWSIXZDFMQUQ
>  =>
>  orugkidqmfzxg53pojsduicxijevoskgkvhfsicxjfeukq2zeaugq2looq5ca2luebuxgidon52ca4tpoqytgidfnzrw6zdfmquq

as:

> BASE32 code and it translates to: `the password: WBIWIFUNY WIIECY (hint: it is not rot13 encoded)`

that translates with caesar +20 (or +6 for decrypt) as:

> CHOCOLATE COOKIE

Comment: Well done, enjoy your cookie! :)

Answer (score 9):

Partial currently:

> The cipher could be decoded by phone keypad(e.g. 777 -> R, 9999 -> Z), and the prologue sentence is **remove all spaces and replace the numbers with digits to proceed**.
>
>  For the latter cipher, I found several numbers written in English in order, translate to numeric: **5322525246**.
>
>   Still working on this number string.

Update:

> Provide the 10x10 cipher grid suggested by Stiv here:
>
> ```
>  o r u g k i d g m f
>
>  z x g 5 3 p o j s d
>
>  u i c x i j e v o s
>
>  k g k v h f s i c x
>
>  j f e u k g 2 z e a
>
>  u g q 2 l o o q 5 c
>
>  a 2 l u e b u x g i
>
>  d o n 5 2 c a 4 t p
>
>  o q y t g i d f n z
>
>  r w 6 z d f m q u q
> ```

Comment: That is correct so far :)

Comment: An observation: Once you carry out the coded instruction you end up with a string of exactly 100 letters and numbers - this might lend itself nicely to being arranged as a grid of 10x10 or something else similar, which might be a way forward...

Comment: Happy to see you guys working on it. Let me know if you need a hint :)

Comment: Hmm maybe yes... :( still no finding on the 10x10 cipher board.

Comment: @Conifers Sorry for my inactivity. I've added a hint to the question. Regarding the 10x10 cipher board: ROT13(GUVF VF ABG YRNQVAT GB N FBYHGVBA CHAXG)

Comment: @Conifers You made two mistakes in g->q.

Comment: @JanIvan Oops my mistake... And congra for the decoding :D

Answer (score 2):

The password is:

> Edible

Explanation:

> It is literally stated in the question.